# Removing a UIView and bringing back the UIView in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am using a UIView not a view controller/ I am removing the view once the delete button is clicked. I am trying to make the view come back when a user wants the view back. 
example : myView.removeFromSuperview() 
Is there anyway to bring the view back? 
In swift thank you guys!

```
@IBOutlet weak var brokeView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var deleteButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func deleteViewButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        if brokeView != nil {
            brokeView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
```

Comment: myView.addSubview(myView) @Vladimir

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
@IBOutlet weak var brokeView: UIView!
```

you already have a reference to the view `brokeView` which you are going to remove and add again, but its `weak` so it will be deallocated once it is removed from `superView`. Since you need this `brokeView` to add back make it `strong`.

```
@IBOutlet var brokeView: UIView!
```

Now you can add it back like

```
view.addSubview(brokeView)
```

Comment: Please note that if the child view that is being removed has any constraints referencing its super view, these constraints will no longer exist when adding it back to the super view.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to get it back unless you initialise it again. You can hide the view and unhide it.

```
viewToBeHidden.hidden = true
//when you want to make it reappear unhide it.
viewToBeHidden.hidden = false
```

Or like @rmaddy suggested keep the reference.

```
var myView = UIView()
myView.removeFromSuperview
//then just add it back.
self.view.addSubView(myView)
```

Comment: You don't need to get it back or reinitialize it. Just save a reference to it so you can put it back.

Comment: @rmaddy how do you do that, could you show an exmple

Answer (score 0):

if you removing it from superview, you can add it again, but you should not make that view as nil other wise you will have to create new one.Removing from superview only remove view from parent view.

```
subview.removeFromSuperview() // remove from parent view

parentView.addSubview(subview) //adding again on it parent view
```

Create a View:
This sample, it depends on your view which init method, you have created, used that one.

```
MyCustomView *customView = MyCustomView(frame: CGRectZero(top: 0, left: 0, width: 200, height: 50)
self.view.addSubview(customView)
```

Comment: how would i create a new one? Thanks for the help

Comment: Thank you for your help! I had to make the variable strong!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `IBoutlet` you need to remove `weak` from your `IBoutlet` after you remove `weak` you remove and add the view again to your view but you need to set the constraints programmatically to view.

Example:

```
// removed 'weak' reference
@IBOutlet var mButton: UIButton!

... other functionality

// remove from superview
mButton.removeFromSuperview()

// add again to view
view.addSubview(mButton)
               
// set re-set constraints 
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                    mButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:       view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
                    mButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -40)
                ])
```